# Java beginner coordinate out of bounds

Tags: java

I have been learning about how to rotate picture and I have to rotate a picture 180 and 270 degrees. I haven't started on the 270 and I can't seem to figure out how to fix the out of bounds errors.

```
public Picture rotate180()
{
    Picture rotated = new Picture ();

    for (int x = 0, roty = 0; x < getWidth(); x++, roty++)
    {
      for (int y = 0, rotx = getWidth()-1; y<getHeight(); y++, rotx--)
      {
        Pixel oldPixel = getPixel(x,y);
        Pixel newPixel = getPixel(rotx,roty);
        newPixel.setColor(oldPixel.getColor());
      }
    }
return rotated;
}
```

Comment: you aren't returning anything even though you method has a `Picture` return type

Comment: I actually just edited that, I realized after posting that I cut off the return part. All fixed on that.

Comment: Do you get an out of bounds exception on the rotate180()? In which line? Also, the return value **rotated** is not changed at all after creation. The method should get **newPixel** from **rotated** and then set its color.

Comment: I've pretty much been going in circles on this. We only learned about rotating 90 by swapping x and y. The code compiles just fine but as soon as I try to run the method I just get all of the errors.

Comment: @CBlair can you show code for `rotate90()`?

Comment: The error should tell you on what line it is and what the number is that is out of bounds. That should be enough to figure out what's going wrong. You should always post **the exact error message** when asking a question about an error you're getting. And we likely also need **a complete program**, because the issue could very well be somewhere other than the code you've shown. Also, you never use `rotated`, you seem to be just overwriting the pixels in the existing image (but that shouldn't cause an out of bounds exception with 180 degree rotation).

Comment: Here's the error code that I'm getting in the interactions panel java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
 at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
 at SimplePicture.getBasicPixel(SimplePicture.java:300)
 at Pixel.getColor(Pixel.java:184)
 at Picture.rotate180(Picture.java:101)

Comment: the only line that is in the method is 101. that line is just for newPixel.newPixel.setColor (oldPixel.getColor());

Answer (score 1):

```java
private enum Degree {
    _90_ {
        public Picture rotate(Picture picture) {
            Picture res = swapRowCol(new Picture(picture.height, picture.width), picture);

            // mirror each column
            for (int col = 0; col < res.width; col++)
                for (int row1 = 0, row2 = res.height - 1; row1 < row2; row1++, row2--)
                    swapColor(res, col, row1, col, row2);

            return res;
        }
    },
    _180_ {
        public Picture rotate(Picture picture) {
            Picture res = new Picture(picture.width, picture.height);

            // desc rows and mirror each one
            for (int row1 = 0, row2 = res.height - 1; row1 < res.height; row1++, row2--)
                for (int col1 = 0, col2 = picture.width - 1; col1 < picture.width; col1++, col2--)
                    res.getPixel(col2, row2).setColor(picture.getPixel(col1, row1).getColor());

            return res;
        }
    },
    _270_ {
        public Picture rotate(Picture picture) {
            Picture res = swapRowCol(new Picture(picture.height, picture.width), picture);

            // mirror each row
            for (int row = 0; row < res.height; row++)
                for (int col1 = 0, col2 = res.width - 1; col1 < col2; col1++, col2--)
                    swapColor(res, col1, row, col2, row);

            return res;
        }
    };

    public abstract Picture rotate(Picture picture);

    protected static Picture swapRowCol(Picture dst, Picture src) {
        // (x;y) -> (y;x)
        for (int row = 0; row < src.height; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < src.width; col++)
                dst.getPixel(row, col).setColor(src.getPixel(col, row).getColor());

        return dst;
    }

    protected static void swapColor(Picture res, int srcCol, int srcRow, int dstCol, int dstRow) {
        Pixel pixel1 = res.getPixel(srcCol, srcRow);
        Pixel pixel2 = res.getPixel(dstCol, dstRow);
        int color = pixel1.getColor();
        pixel1.setColor(pixel2.getColor());
        pixel2.setColor(color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In more general case, for rotate to any angle, you have to use **javax.imageio.***

```java
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public final class ImageUtils {
    public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage image, int degreeAngle) {
        degreeAngle = normalizeAngle(degreeAngle);

        if (degreeAngle == 0 || image == null)
            return image;

        double theta = Math.toRadians(degreeAngle);
        double cosTheta = Math.abs(Math.cos(theta));
        double sinTheta = Math.abs(Math.sin(theta));
        int width = (int)Math.rint(image.getWidth() * cosTheta + image.getHeight() * sinTheta);
        int height = (int)Math.rint(image.getWidth() * sinTheta + image.getHeight() * cosTheta);
        Graphics2D graphics = null;

        try {
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            graphics = rotatedImage.createGraphics();

            at.rotate(theta, image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2);
            at.preConcatenate(balanceImagePosition(at, image));

            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            graphics.drawRenderedImage(image, at);

            return rotatedImage;
        } finally {
            if (graphics != null)
                graphics.dispose();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Transform given angle in degree of any range to the [0;360) range
     *
     * @param degreeAngle angle in degree
     * @return normalized angle in degree
     */
    private static int normalizeAngle(int degreeAngle) {
        if (degreeAngle <= -360 || degreeAngle >= 360)
            degreeAngle %= 360;
        if (degreeAngle < 0)
            degreeAngle += 360;

        return degreeAngle;
    }

    private static AffineTransform balanceImagePosition(AffineTransform at, BufferedImage image) {
        Point2D[] points = { new Point2D.Double(0, 0), new Point2D.Double(image.getWidth(), 0), new Point2D.Double(0,
                image.getHeight()), new Point2D.Double(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()) };
        double tx = image.getWidth();
        double ty = image.getHeight();

        for (Point2D point : points) {
            Point2D tmp = at.transform(point, null);
            tx = Math.min(tx, tmp.getX());
            ty = Math.min(ty, tmp.getY());
        }

        at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(-tx, -ty);

        return at;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, your for loops are not doing anything to Picture rotated. I assume that your "getWidth()" call is supposed to get the width of 'rotated'. If so, then you need to put rotated.getWidth() to access that property. Use the same approach in the rest of your code too. `rotated.getHeight();
rotated.getPixel (x, y)`
etc. 
Also, you are using two int values as increments in your for loop that are always equal, you can just use the one.